# Bootstrap Tooltip should not hide or disapperar on focusing on tooltip content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have implemented bootstrap tooltip in my project. I want to hide or disappear tooltip only when user focus outside only . When user focus on tooltip  content it should not hide or disappear but it is hiding can anybody tell how to hide or disappear tooltip content when user focus outside ?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" data-placement="top">Hover over me</a>

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
container: 'body',
boundary: 'window',
trigger: 'focus hover',
html: true,
template:   
 '<div class="tooltip bs-tooltip-top" role="tooltip">'+
  '<div class="arrow"></div>'+
  '<div class="tooltip-inner">'+
  '</div>'+
'</div>'+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This example is working if this is what you are searching for.
Here is the fiddle if you like to play a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/8Ln7z0te/4/

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'hover focus',
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: "And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?",
    title: "Popover title",
    html: true,
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover">Click to toggle popover</button>
```